# hasura database connection failing with error : password authentication failed for user postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, hasura

As per the removal of Heroku free product plans. I planned to switch the my application database into rds postgres db, and i setup all those things as per the hasura doc.

The issue is when i try to connect the database its showing:

```
password authentication failed for user postgres
```

I didn't created an separate database user so i go with default one `postgres` and for password i was using the password which i generated while creating the database.

Things i have done:

- I checked and verified the password i entered on both places
- Modified the password and tried again

How to get rid of this password failing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by removing default user name `postgres` to `name-of-db`.

After replacing database name instead of default postgres it got connected